# Using Having in SQL but not getting any results

Tags: sql

I want results by conditions between three tables

```
Givers, Yateem, TakeMoney
```

**Givers**

```
AccountNo, Mobile
```

**Yateem**

```
AccountNo, Money
```

**TakeMoney**

```
AccountNo, MoneyTaken
```

Show all `AccountNo` from `TakeMoney` not in `Givers`, or in `Givers` but

```
sum(TakeMoney.MoneyTaken) < Sum(Yateem.Money) * '3'

where TakeMoney.date Like '10-10-2020'
```

I used this but it does not work

```
SELECT
    Givers.AccountNo, Givers.GMob, 
    COALESCE(SUM(Yateem.Money), 0) AS YateemMoney,    
    COALESCE(SUM(Yateem.Money), 0) * '3' AS MonWant
FROM
    Givers
LEFT JOIN 
    Yateem ON Givers.AccountNo = Yateem.AccountNo
GROUP BY 
    Givers.AccountNo, Givers.GMob
HAVING 
    COALESCE(COUNT(Yateem.Money), 0) > '0' 
    AND (AccountNo NOT IN (SELECT AccountNo FROM TakeMoney 
                           WHERE date LIKE '10-10-2020') 
         OR COALESCE(COUNT(Yateem.Money), 0) * '3' > (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(MoneyTaken), 0) 
                                                      FROM TakeMoney 
                                                      WHERE date LIKE '10-10-2020')
```

Comment: Could you please provide sample data and expected data. Which DBMS you are using ? Why count > '0' and this condition should be part of where clause `(AccountNo not in(select AccountNo from TakeMoney Where date Like '10-10-2020')`

Comment: I want display TakeMoney.AccountNo if not found in this date or found but sum(Yateem.Money) Not 0 and sum(Yateem.Money)*'3' > sum(TakeMoney.MoneyTaken) in this date

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation *in the question* would all help me better understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Numeric data are no strings: `* '3'` => `* 3`

`COALESCE(Count(Yateem.Money),0) > '0'` is the same as `Count(Yateem.Money) > 0` and turns the Outer join into an Inner join.

`(AccountNo not in(select` should result in an *ambigous column name* error because it's not qualified.

`COALESCE(Count(Yateem.Money),0)*'3' > (select COALESCE(Sum(MoneyTaken),0)` compares a count of rows with a sum of money? Btw, again no COALESCE needed.

`date Like '10-10-2020'` Date comparison using LIKE? no matter if `date` is a date or a string, LIKE is useless and exactly the same as `=`

Comment: I don't know what you actually want, your explanation is not ervy clear.

Comment: I want display AccountNo in TakeMoney table is null in any date or AccountNo not null but sum(MoneyTake) in TakeMoney table < count(Yateem.money)*3 in Yateem table